# App Engine urlfetch verify_certificate

Tags: google-app-engine

App Engine python runtime, latest SDK ... using urlfetch to request over https. No matter what value I use for verify_certificate (True, False, None), I get back the same response from an internal site with a fake certificate, 
Invalid and/or missing SSL certificate for URL:

The documentation suggests that setting verify_certificate to False should bypass this check. But again, I get the same exception no matter what I use. I checked the bug database but did not find anything.

We are using a made up certificate because we want the data encrypted over the wire, but we can trust the endpoint as it is internal.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your self made certificate is valid and installed correctly by accessing the endpoint using other software such as curl, wget or a web browser.  You might have already done that, but the question does not (yet) say so.

If other software can access the endpoint but the url fetch service still cannot, then please report the problem with a link to your question in the [AppEngine Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?can=2&q=Type=Defect).  Thank you.